# Как написать вызов callback так чтобы вызов result происходил из callback?

Tags: c#, async-await, делегаты

Есть метод

```
public async void GetCandlsAsync(Action<ObservableCollection<Candle>, Exception> callback)
{

    var result = await Task<ObservableCollection<Candle>>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        var item = new ObservableCollection<Candle>();
        Random r = new Random();

        decimal? close = (decimal?)r.Next(300) / 100;
        var date = DateTime.Now;
        date = date.AddSeconds(-date.Second);

        for(int i = 200; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            decimal? open = close;
            close = open + ((decimal?)r.Next(400) - 200) / 100;
            decimal? low = Math.Min(Convert.ToDecimal(open), Convert.ToDecimal(close)) -
                           ((decimal?)r.Next(100) / 100);
            decimal? high = Math.Max(Convert.ToDecimal(open), Convert.ToDecimal(close)) +
                            ((decimal?)r.Next(200) / 100);
            item.Add(new Candle(date.AddMinutes(-i), open, high, low, close));
        }
        return item;
    });


    callback(result, null);

}
```

как написать вызов callback так чтобы вызов result происходил из callback? Т.е. в итоге хочу чтобы было

```
public async void GetCandlsAsync(Action<ObservableCollection<Candle>, Exception> callback)
        {
callback ((...... => {.....}, null);
}
```

Comment: Не вполне понятна цель такого действия. Почему вас не устраивает существующий код?

Answer (score 1):

```
callback (await Task<ObservableCollection<Candle>>.Factory.StartNew(() => {
  // ...
}), null);
```

Но я бы не советовал писать код таким образом.

Comment: Дополните ответ пожалуйста, почему бы вы не советовали так писать.